# Inner For Loop not executing in App Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, nested-loops

**Context**

In google app script for gsheets I am running this function that searches the names of items in a comma separated list within a single cell per row, against a list of item name and ids in 2 columns.

The function is called within another function that iterates through each row of data in the Data Table.

The goal is to replace the names with the ids in a comma separated list.

**The Problem**

The nested loop just doesn't run! When I set up training outputs to test where the code gets blocked it's at the inner for loop, it breaks at that line and doesn't execute at all. I cannot figure out why that would be as I can't see a problem with my syntax.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong please?

**The data looks like this:**

```
Item Directory Table:

Item ID | Item Name
--------------------
1234    | Item 1
46976   | Item 2
3526    | Item 3
32255   | Item 4
425     | Item 5  


Data table:

Data Name | Items
--------------------
Row 1     | Item 1, Item 2, Item 5
Row 2     | Item 5, Item 2
Row 3     | Item 4
Row 4     | 
Row 5     | Item 1
```

**Desired output:**

```
Row 1 = [1234, 46976, 425] // updated item 2
Row 2 = [425, 46976]
Row 3 = [32255]
Row 4 = []
Row 5 = [1234]
```

**This is my function:**

```
function findItems(x) {
  var items = [];
  var j = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var itemNames = Items.getRange(2 ,11).getValue().split(', ');
  var itemIDs = Items.getRange(3 ,11).getValue().split(', ');
  
  if (data.getRange(x, 6).getValue() != '') {
    items = data.getRange(x, 6).getValue().split(', ');
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      output.getRange(2, 1).setValue(items[i]);
      for (j = 0; j < itemNames.length; j++) {
       if (items[i] === itemNames[j]) {
          items[i] = itemIDs[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return items
}
```

Comment: If the inner loop is not executing it just means the condition part of the for-loop is  not satisfied.

Comment: I am not against GAS, but I think in your scenario a google formula would be more suitable unless you don't have other option rather than using GAS.

Comment: Your desired output is easily obtained with an object that converts item names to IDs and a single loop

Comment: If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will provide below is a one-time run for all rows. Feel free to modify to get your expected behavior, you can add a parameter or call the function as formula to populate the cells one by one.

```
function findItems() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ids = sheet.getRange('A2:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var names = sheet.getRange('B2:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var data = sheet.getRange('C2:C' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var items = sheet.getRange('D2:D' + lastRow).getValues();

  items.forEach(function(item, count){
    var elems = item[0].split(",");
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++){
        if(elems[i].trim() == names[j].trim()){
          elems[i] = ids[j];
          break;
        }
      }
    }    
    // separated the formatting so you can easily modify here
    // followed the formatting in your post
    var output = data[count] + ' = [' + elems.join(', ') + ']';
    sheet.getRange('E' + (count + 2)).setValue(output);
  });
}
```

This is the expected output from this code.

[image: sample output]

If you want to return something, you might want to modify the code above as this only sets the string `output` as the cell's value.

Logic is pretty straight forward, but if you have any clarifications/questions, feel free to comment below.